# When executing a command through java runtime (in a docker container), I get command not found

Tags: java, docker, shell, kotlin

I'm trying to spin up the kotlin compiler through java. I've tried the following commands:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kotlinc -version").waitFor()`

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kotlin -version").waitFor()`

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash", "-c", "kotlin -version").waitFor()`

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh", "-c", "kotlin -version").waitFor()`

and each time I get a variant of "no such directory" or "command not found".

Yet, when I connect to the container's terminal (user is "app") and do `kotlinc` it works as expected. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't try `exec("kotlinc", "-version")`. Or did you?

Comment: You can also try to find what's the absolute path of `kotlinc` and use it instead.

Comment: I have tried that, to no avail :/ Not a bad shout, I'll give it a go

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use `ProcessBuilder` with `inheritIO` and yes, using the full path to the compiler is a good idea